# How to add new alert rules to prometheus?

Tags: alert, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

Im trying to add a new rule to prometheus, I'm wondering what command should i use to add the rule at k8s branch cluster.

I tried `k apply -f rules.yml`, however, i met this:

```
error: error validating "rules/alert_rules.yml": error validating data: [apiVersion not set, kind not set]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

here is the rules.xml i tried, anything wrong?

```
groups:
  - name: sf_usage_alert
    rules:
      - alert: usage_exceed
        expr: http_request_daily_usage_of_salesforce > 100000
        labels:
          severity: urgent
```

Comment: Are you using prometheus operator?

Comment: yes, it is prometheus operator